# C++ STL's copy() exception safety

Tags: c++, exception, stl

If I do

```
std::copy(source, source + size, destination);
```

Do I have strong exception safety guarantee? I.e. if std::copy throws, destination is left unchanged?

Comment: Post a reply with reference please.

Comment: How could it? Eventually it must start touching destination and if that stops working half way through destination is left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Just think about it for 10 seconds. The only possible way would be to backup the destination before copying. There are at least reasons why that's a terrible idea even when it's possible: (1) it would require allocating additional memory, (2) it would be slow as heck, and (3) the copying (to back up) as well as the restoration (from backup) could easily throw another exception the same way the original threw an exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the standard:

> **25.3.1 Copy**  [alg.copy]
>
> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
>    OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>                        OutputIterator result);
> ```
>
> 1 *Effects:* Copies elements in the range `[first,last)` into the range `[result,result + (last -first))` starting from `first` and proceeding to `last`. For each non-negative integer `n < (last -first)`, performs `*(result + n) = *(first + n)`.
>
> 2 *Returns:* `result + (last - first).`
>
> 3 *Requires:* `result` shall not be in the range `[first,last)`.
>
> 4 *Complexity:* Exactly `last - first` assignments.

It does not make any guarantees about exception safety. It also does not specify what the behavior would be if `result` is in the range `[first,last)`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be listed alongside each algorithm, there could be a general statement earlier that covers a group of algorithms. Anyway, the real problem with providing a strong exception guarantee would be what T.C. says in this answer - if `result` is a write-only output iterator, there's no way to *rollback* to the original contents.

Comment: And even if you **could** rollback, you shouldn't try. What if that throws a **second** exception ?!

Answer (score 15):

**Appendix E: Standard-Library Exception Safety** from  Stroustrop's *The C++ Programming Language* is [freely viewable from his website](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf).

From that:

> The `copy()` algorithm (§18.6.1) does *not* offer the strong
> exception-safety guarantee. It does not guarantee that it will leave its target unchanged if an exception
> is thrown during copying

Answer (score 9):

A quick search through Clause 25 (the clause specifying most standard algorithms) shows that there are no instance of the phrase *no effects*, and the standard specifies strong exception safety as "if an exception is thrown (there are/the function has) no effects". In other words, nothing in Clause 25 has the strong exception safety guarantee.

Besides, how could `std::copy` possibly offer the strong exception safety guarantee? `dest` can be an arbitrary output iterator that isn't necessarily readable, and can perform arbitrary operations on a write. What if it's a `std::ostream_iterator` - how do you "un-write" what's been written into the stream?

Answer (score 6):

Copy is defined in 25.3.1 as

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
OutputIterator result);
1 Effects: Copies elements in the range [first,last) into the range [result,result + (last -
first)) starting from first and proceeding to last. For each non-negative integer n < (last -
first), performs *(result + n) = *(first + n).
2 Returns: result + (last - first).
3 Requires: result shall not be in the range [first,last).
4 Complexity: Exactly last - first assignments.
```

Which can be effectively written as:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    *result = *first;
    ++result; ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The way that it is formatted if the exception happens any time after the first execution of the loop then the the destination will be changed.